# Pass method and call inside function

Tags: c#, reflection

i have object `var channel = new Chanel();`
this object has several methods which i call inside function like this:

```
private bool GetMethodExecution()
{
   var channel = new Channel();
   channel.method1();
   channel.method2();
}
```

all methods of class `Channel` derives from interface `IChannel`.
My question is how can i call method `GetMethodExecution()` and pass which *method* I want to execute and then execute it inside this function based on parameter passed.

What i need is to call GetMethodExectution(IChannle.method1) and then call it on object inside this function. Is this possible

Comment: What is the larger context? Why are you sure that `Reflection` is the best choice? Why won't you call methods separately depending on application state?

Comment: honestly I think that Action or Func might be helpfull here but didn't know how to use it.

Comment: Based on what kind of parameter passed? Do you want to pass the method name that you want to Invoke?

Comment: @Zefnus yes exactly this is what i want to achieve.

Comment: @Zefnus this is true, i thought more that it is possible to use interface some how as enum, without implementing it, just take some information of it, pass into the method and then use it on object which implement that interface. And seems it is immposible so i accepted answer the closest one.

Comment: @kosnkov so all methods you want to *Invoke* in `GetMethodExecution()` is defined in `IChannel` *Interface* and will be implemented by derived classes. Since you can't instantiate an *Interface*, you will need to pass the *derived instance* or implement it as *extension method* for `IChannel`. Assuming multiple methods are defined in `IChannel`, how do you desire to **decide** which Method to Invoke?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private bool GetMethodExecution(Func<Channel, bool> channelExecutor)
{
   var channel = new Channel();
   return channelExecutor(channel);
}
```

Now you can pass method via lambda like:

```
GetMethodExecution(ch => ch.method1());

GetMethodExecution(ch => ch.method2());
```

Comment: ok but i want to call all those methods inside GetMethodExecution and those method dont take any arguments all what i need is to call GetMethodExectution(IChannle.method1) is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
private bool GetMethodExecution(int method)
{
   switch (method)
   {
       case 1: return new Channel().method1();
       case 2: return new Channel().method2();
       default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("method");
   }
}
```

```
GetMethodExecution(1);
GetMethodExecution(2);
```

Comment: much more Func but method has no arquments

Comment: `GetMethodExecution(1);` it is not obvious which method will be executed. Consider the difference between method calls `Move(3)` and `Move(player => player.Left())`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as following using `Func` *Delegate*:

```
private bool GetMethodExecution(Func<bool> Method)
{
    return Method()
}

public bool YourCallingMethod()
{
    var channel = new Channel();         
    return GetMethodExecution(channel.method1); // Or return GetMethodExecution(channel.method2);
}
```

Comment: this is almost the answer but in this case i need to create object outside the GetMethodExecution and then pass its method, but this object is of the Interface which i know, so I would like to pass minimum information like which method of the interface to call and then keep calling and creation inside this method.

Comment: The syntax isn't quite right; you're invoking `method1` not passing it.  You need to remove the parens after the method name to pass the delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass **method name** as parameter and Invoke it inside your code block, you can use reflection as follows:

```
private bool GetMethodExecution(string methodName)
{
   var channel = new Channel();

   Type type = typeof(Channel);
   MethodInfo info = type.GetMethod(methodName);

   return (bool)info.Invoke(channel, null); // # Assuming the methods you call return bool
}
```